# Accessing interface builder object from view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm completely new to Objective-C, XCode, and iOS development and I'm trying to figure out how to run certain code at startup, after all UI views and controls have been instantiated. I have a generic NSObject that I've added through interface builder by dragging it into my view controller scene. It's defined as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Controller : NSObject {
    IBOutlet UISlider *slider;        
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}

-(IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender;

@end
```

I need to run sliderChanged on initialization. I've tried the following way:

```
#import "Controller.h"

@implementation Controller

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        [self sliderChanged:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
// More code here
```

But both my slider and label are nil when this is called. I understand there's a `viewDidLoad` method within the `ViewController` class which may be what I need, but I'm not sure how to access the instance of my `Controller` class (which seems to be instantiated somewhere behind the scenes by the interface builder) from within that method. Should all of this code simply be moved to the `ViewController` itself? That would seem to make sense, but the design above is what we've been instructed in class, so I'm not really sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the XIB/Storyboard loader finishes loading all the objects and wiring them up, it sends `awakeFromNib` to every object that was instantiated from the XIB.  So try adding this to your `Controller` class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self sliderChanged:nil];
}
```

You can find more information in the [*NSObject UIKit Additions Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [“The Nib Object Life Cycle” in the *Resource Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW18).

**HOWEVER**, if you created `Controller` as a top-level object, and you didn't connect any outlets **to** it, then nothing references it after the XIB loader finishes with it, so the system will deallocate it again.  That's probably not what you want, so you should connect an outlet in your view controller to the `Controller`.  If you do that (and let's say the outlet is named `controller`), then you can access it in `viewDidLoad` in your view controller class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Controller.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet Controller *controller;
}
@end
```

Implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.controller sliderChanged:self];
}
```

Comment: Second solution was exactly what I needed. Cheers!